# Can adjacency lists be used in directed graphs?

Tags: adjacency-matrix

I've been reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list

[image]

It says that that graph can be constructed with the list $\{b, c\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, b\}$.

However, what if I wanted to construct a directional list? Does $\{b, c\}$ point to $b$ or $c$?

How can you use a list to represent a directional graph?

Answer (score 2):

Your graph is actually undirected. The notation is a list of *edges* in the graph. Since edges are undirected, each edge is a *set* of two vertices. Your lists contains three edges, since a triangle has three edges. It actually contains *all* possible edges involving the vertices $a,b,c$.

A *directed graph* is one in which edges consist of two *ordered* vertices. The edge points from the first vertex to the second. You can represent such a graph using a list of pairs.

*Adjacency lists* are a different data structure, which is described in the Wikipedia page you link to, so I skip its description here. It can be used for both undirected and directed graphs, in the natural way.

Answer (score 2):

> Does $\{b,c\}$ point to $b$ or $c$?

Neither.  The adjacency list representation of a graph, you are given, for each vertex $x$, a list of the vertices adjacent to $x$.  Thus, the lists $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{a,b\}$, tell you that $a$ is adjacent to $b$ and $c$, $b$ is adjacent to $a$ and $c$ and $c$ $is$ adjacent to $a$ and $b$.

You shouldn't confuse this with the notation $\{x,y\}$ for the undirected edge connecting $x$ and $y$.